# How do I go to previous page in gatsby (history.goBack)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I am working on gatsby. I need to go back to privious page/link as I used to do with reactjs.

```
<a onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack}>
  <button type="button" className="close_tab">
    <img src={Close} alt="" />
  </button>
</a>
```

How can I do this using gatsby?

Answer (score 20):

Use `navigate(-1)`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";

export default function GoBack() {
  return (
    <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
      Go Back
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: Since `reach-router@1.3.0`, you can now simply call `navigate(-1)` to go back. Manually update reach-router in your Gatsby project if it's not yet updated. Thanks @nathan in the comment for the tip.

---

**Edit**: Ah alright, I've just realized `this.props.history.goBack` is a `react-router` thing. Gatsby doesn't use `react-router`, but `reach-router` under the hood and it doesn't have the `history` props or the `goBack` method. [There's a issue requesting to add this](https://github.com/reach/router/issues/44), but wasn't implemented. You'd have to use browser's own history object as I suggested below.

```js
import React from 'react'

const BackButton = React.forwardRef(
  ({ children, ...props }, ref) => {
    const onClick = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      history.back()
    }
    return (
      <a {...props} ref={ref} href="#" onClick={onClick}>
        {children}
      </a>
    )
  }
)

BackButton.displayName = 'BackButton'
export { BackButton }
```

---

Is `this.props.history` the browser's history? If so, you can do `this.props.history.go(-1)` to go back to the previous page.

As always with Gatsby, watch out when you use methods from browser, since they don't exist during html generation:

```js
export default () => (
  <button onClick={() => {
    typeof history !== 'undefined' && history.go(-1)
  }}>back</button>
)
```

Comment: Check the PR again, it's been merged in `1.3.0`. Use `navigate(-1)`

Comment: @nathan thanks for the tip, will update the answer accordingly

Comment: ;) But 1.3.0 is still in beta so it will take a while to be merged into gatsby

Answer (score 1):

For a function component in Gatsby:

```
   <a onClick={() => window.history.back()}>Go back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The gatsby navigate function is type as NavigateFn.

Which you can find declare as:

```
export interface NavigateFn {
    (to: string, options?: NavigateOptions<{}>): Promise<void>;
    (to: number): Promise<void>;
}
```

So, as you can see, you either can pass the route you want to redirect to, or an specific number.

Try with `navigate(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import { navigate } from "@gatsbyjs/reach-router";

 <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back to previous page</button>
```

It goes to the previous page